# Finding primes such that 2 in a non-n-tic residue

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does or does not the following conjecture hold?

> For any integer $n \ge 2$, there exist a infinite number of primes $p$ so that for all integers $x$, $$x^n \not \equiv 2 \pmod {p}$$

This is clearly true for $n=2$, as for primes $p \equiv \pm 3 \pmod {8}$ we have that $2$ is a non-quadratic residue.

However, I am not so sure for $n \ge 3$. Can someone provide some assistance?

Also, I would say that I would not be able to understand a non-elementary proof very well.

Comment: Note that if $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $p$, it is also not a $4$-tic (fourth power) residue mod $p$ for any such prime.  More generally it will not be a $2k$-power mod $p$.  Similarly you could reduce the conjecture to considering only prime exponents $n$.

Comment: I imagine that you could be fairly confident of the truth of this, even extending to: $$ x^n \not\equiv q \pmod p$$ for any fixed $q$ prime (or possible even just $q$ square-free). I see no special reason to expect a modular high power to "land on" a particular number that is not intrinsically a high power.

Comment: UserUserUserUSerUser